# File.open with block vs without

Tags: ruby, koan

I have a question about Block, do the two codes mean the same?

code 1

```
File::open('yozloy.txt','w') do |f|
  f << 'Some contains'
end
```

code 2

```
newFile = File::open('yozloy.txt','w')
newFile << 'Some contains'
```

Comment: I don't think it matters so much, but it's far more common to write class methods as `File.open` rather than `File::open`.

Comment: `code 2` will not close the file automatically, like `code 1` does. So you will need to do `newFile.close`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

DarkDust already said that these methods are different. I'll explain you the blocks a little more, as I suppose that I can guess why you asked this question ;-)

The block in ruby is just a parameter for some method. It's not just a different syntax.

Methods which accept (optional) blocks usually have a condition to test whether they have been called with block, or without.

Consider this very simplified example: (the real File.open is similar, but it ensures the file is closed even if your block raises an error, for example)

```
def open(fname)
  self.do_open(fname)
  if block_given?
    yield(self) # This will 'run' the block with given parameter
    self.close
  else
    return self # This will just return some value
  end
end
```

In general, every method may work (works) differently with a block or without a block. It should be always stated in the method documentation.

Comment: I am new to Ruby and I can't run your code. I tried "file = open(file_name)" but I get undefined method `do_open' for main:Object (NoMethodError). Where does this do_open method come from?

Comment: Uh, sorry for the answer coming 4 years too late. ;) If someone else would be having the same problem: my code was just supposed to illustrate the concepts. It was NOT a working example. In the real code, you would have to write both methods (`do_open` and `close`) yourself.

Answer (score 42):

No, they do not mean the same. In the first example, the file is automatically closed after the block was processed. In the second example, it's your responsibility to manually call `newFile.close`.