# Refactoring my code so that file closes automatically once loaded, how does the syntax work?

Tags: ruby, file, methods, syntax

My program loads a list from a file, and I'm trying to change the method so that it closes automatically.

I've looked at the Ruby documentation, [the broad stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224587/file-open-with-block-vs-without), and [this guy's website](http://benjamintan.io/blog/2015/03/28/ruby-block-patterns-and-how-to-implement-file-open/), but the syntax is always different and doesn't mean much to me yet.

My original load:

```
def load_students(filename = "students.csv")
  if filename == nil
    filename = "students.csv"
  elsif filename == ''
    filename = "students.csv"
  end
  file = File.open(filename, "r")
  file.readlines.each do |line|
    name, cohort = line.chomp.split(",")
    add_students(name).to_s
  end
  file.close
  puts "List loaded from #{filename}."
end
```

My attempt to close automatically:

```
def load_students(filename = "students.csv")
  if filename == nil
    filename = "students.csv"
  elsif filename == ''
    filename = "students.csv"
  end
  open(filename, "r", &block)
  line.each do |line|
    name, cohort = line.chomp.split(",")
    add_students(name).to_s
  end
  puts "List loaded from #{filename}."
end
```

I'm looking for the same result, but without having to manually close the file.

I don't think it'll be much different, so how does the syntax work for automatically closing with blocks?

Comment: The file would be closed automatically by ruby when the local variable `file` ceases to exist after the method execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File.open(filename, 'r') do |file|
  file.readlines.each do |line|
    name, cohort = line.chomp.split(",")
    add_students(name).to_s
  end
end
```

---

I’d refactor the whole code:

```
def load_students(filename = "students.csv")
  filename = "students.csv" if filename.to_s.empty?
  File.open(filename, "r") do |file|
    file.readlines.each do |line|
      add_students(line.chomp.split(",").first)
    end
  end
  puts "List loaded from #{filename}."
end
```

---

Or, even better, as suggested by Kimmo Lehto in comments:

```
def load_students(filename = "students.csv")
  filename = "students.csv" if filename.to_s.empty?
  File.foreach(filename) do |line|
    add_students(line.chomp.split(",").first)
  end
  puts "List loaded from #{filename}."
end
```

Comment: No need for open, just use `File.foreach(filename) do |line|`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev for the list of students? Maybe when run on Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: it's thinking like this is what makes an empty rails app take 300mb of RAM :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I profile everything I publish to the public domain. I do not care about looking up the better method in the documentation when I write a one-stand script. Feel the difference :)

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: alright, I have another one then: this is why one must not trust code in random posts on stackoverflow. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev this must be graved in stone. I never do. I use SO as write-only resource.